# Call other methods using FXML controller in java?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I created an UI look using JavaFX scene builder and I can use it's controller and when I click a button it prints on the console.

My problem is how I can call other functions from the java program.
When I create a new object in the controller to call other methods I am getting  errors.

Here is a class I want to interact with:

```
   public class GOcommand extends Command {

    public GOcommand(String firstWord, String secondWord, String thirdWord) {
        super(firstWord, secondWord, thirdWord);  
    }

    public GOcommand() {}

    @Override
    public boolean execute(Player player) {
        if (!hasSecondWord()) {
            // if there is no second word, we don't know where to go...
            Game.out.println(Game.messages.getString("goWhere"));
            return false;
        }

        String direction = getSecondWord();
        player.goRoom(direction);
        return false;
    }
    }

Here is the controller class:

    public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    Player player;

    @FXML 
    private TextArea textArea;

     @FXML
    private Button northBtn;

    @FXML
    private Button giveBtn;

    @FXML
    private Button CloseBtn;

    @FXML
    private Button eastBtn;

    @FXML
    private Button dropBtn;

    @FXML
    private Button southBtn;

    @FXML
    private Button WestBtn;

    @FXML
    private Button helpBtn;

    @FXML
    private Button takeBtn;

    @FXML
    private void exitGame() {
       System.exit(1);
    }

    @FXML
    void northClicked(ActionEvent event) {
        textArea.appendText("Go North button Clicked\n");
        player.goRoom("NORTH");
    }

    @FXML
    private void eastClicked(ActionEvent event) {
        textArea.appendText("Go East button Clicked\n");
    }

    @FXML
    private void southClicked(ActionEvent event) {
        textArea.appendText("Go South button Clicked\n");
    }

    @FXML
    private void westClicked(ActionEvent event) {
        textArea.appendText("Go West button Clicked\n");
    }

    @FXML
    private void dropClicked(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    private void takeClicked(ActionEvent event) {
        textArea.appendText("Take button Clicked\n");
    }

    @FXML
    private void giveClicked(ActionEvent event) {
        textArea.appendText("Give button Clicked\n");
    }

    @FXML
    private void helpClicked(ActionEvent event) {
        textArea.appendText("Help me know!\n");
    }


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }
    }
```

And these are the errors because I created the player:

```
 Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:380)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:294)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:415)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at assignment2.FXMLDocumentController.northClicked(FXMLDocumentController.java:62)
    ... 55 more
```

Comment: What errors do you get if you try to call 'other methods'? And could you post your attempt to call these other methods?(e.g. please post your controller class)

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of the stacktrace you posted it shows an NPE, the field 'player' you are accesing. And from what I can see, that field isnt initilized. Otherwise this code would work perfectly fine.

Comment: I created it at the beginning "Player player;" in the controller @n247s

Comment: and this is the part of code in player class:
public Player(String name, Room room) {
        this.name = name;
        currentRoom = room;
        items = new HashMap<>();
    }

Comment: You created the field, but didnt initialized it. (E.g. `Player player = new Player();`

Comment: The problem is that player going through a game and he has name and room parameters, how Am I going to pass these parameters as well? @n247a

Comment: If you want just one player (or one place where player instances are handled) use a getter to get the right player instance.

Comment: The logic is the player walk through the rooms.. my main question is how to use buttons to go up right down left by using the buttons

Comment: instead of writing go up in console

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new instance of Player like:

```
Player player = new Player();
```

An InvocationTargetException in a JavaFX application is often caused by accessing fields which are null. Keep that in mind, when creating JavaFX applications!

Comment: The problem is that player going through a game and he has name and room parameters, how Am I going to pass these parameters as well?